# get facebook user's cover photo via cron

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app that gets its users' cover photos once per day. For this I used to be able to make a request like this:

```
$fb->api("/{$user['fbid']}?fields=cover");
```

And I would get the `source` URL for the user's cover photo.

Now when I make that request I get only the user's ID.

If I go to the app and I go back again to the script that gets the cover photos all works as it used to (I get the cover photo details).

I find it particularly odd that after I go to the app I can not only access `/me?fields=cover` but also `/ANY_ID?field=cover` where `ANY_ID` is any ID that authorized my app. I know that after using my app I set my `access_token`, but shouldn't I only be able to get `/me?fields=?cover" ??

What I need is a way to get my app users' cover photos via a cron (without having to point my browser to the app (to set the access_token)).

This used to work, but is it possible any longer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its is happening because when you are scheduling cron fb user might be not accessibly login and me is only working with login user in fb api as when you are givving userid its working and due to not login session its not able to track me request you may go for login request first before asking for the same in your cron

Comment: I'm requesting `/FBID?fields=cover` not `/me?fields=cover` via the CRON.

Comment: i checked it by graph api with c# script its working good for all account which have cover